# write doubly linked list to a file

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to write a doubly linked list to a textfile.txt
I'm not getting any errors but it is not creating the text file either. The file should simply print in the text file.

```
int getLinkedListsize(char *filename, struct student_record_node* head)
{
      FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"r+");
      struct student_record_node* hit=head;
      int size=0;
      char buffer[2000];

      while(hit!=NULL)
      {
        size += sizeof(head->record_->student_id_) +
                sizeof(head->record_->student_age_) +
                strlen(head->record_->first_name_) +
                strlen(head->record_->last_name_);
        hit=hit->next_;
      }
      return size;
}

void streamNodeList(char *fileName, struct student_record_node* head)
{

      struct student_record_node* iteration= head;
      size_t stream_size=getLinkedListsize(fileName,head);

      FILE* fp = fopen(fileName , "wb");
      fileName="sort_age.txt";
      fwrite(&stream_size,1,sizeof(size_t),fp);
      while(iteration !=NULL)
      {
              fwrite(&(iteration->record_),1,sizeof(iteration->record_),fp);
              iteration =(iteration->next_);
      }

      fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why do you replace the filename *after* opening the file?  Your program may be creating a file somewhere, but w/o knowing how `streamNodeList` is called, can't say where.

Comment: Why open a file in `getLinkedListsize` when there is absolutely no IO operation therein. And you leak the `FILE*` returned from the `fopen` as well, which isn't good either, and probably part of your problem.

Comment: The reason was so i can track back from the name of the text file which i'm assigning to the file ptr.

Comment: @WhozCraig- thank you i'll do that.

Comment: This won't "print to the text file" either when everything is finally fixed. That `fwrite` will write the memory backdrop of whatever your structure looks like to the file. I that structure contains pointers, that certainly isn't going to bode well. And if it contains scalars, their platform-dependent byte ordering will be written. I'm not convinced `fwrite` is your friend for this task.

Comment: @WhozCraig- ok how about fprintf?

Comment: `FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"r+");` requires the file to exist, does it not?  Does the file exist?  You don't check whether the `fopen()` succeeds or not.  However, that's mostly tangential since you don't read from that file (but if it is opened, you leak the file stream — you should check that the open was successful and close before return if it was successful).  Your size calculation is not going to be useful. You don't show the structure, but the `fwrite()` isn't going to honour string lengths. If the elements are arrays, the whole array will be written; if pointers, just the pointer.

Comment: @jonathan Leffler- In my edited code I have fopen, checked for file and then the closed file. Then deleted getLinkListSize funcion, size_t stram from stramNodeList and fwrite then used sprintf, fprintf. As a result it creates the file but don't write to it. The file contains some garbage value.